# Block diagram function to duplicate y-axis in LabVIEW

Tags: graph, labview

I am trying to make a dynamic XY-graph in LabVIEW, in which I'd like to be able to set a number of y-axis during execution. I have so far found only the "mouse-clicky" version of duplicating a y-axes, i.e. right-clicking it on the front panel etc.
Is there a way to do this during execution, via a property node or similar?

Comment: See https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/Programmatically-add-multiple-scales-to-graph/td-p/698476

Comment: okay thank you, that's the solution I'd implemented for now too - tho that forum entry never came up in my searches, unfortunately. nice to hear i'm not the crazy one in requesting this :)

Answer (score 1):

What i would do is to create the amount of Y axis i know a user could use. For example; if you know user could need two Y axis in the application, right click on the Y axis in the chart and duplicate it. This will create two axis in your application with indexes 0 and 1.

Then by using property nodes you can select the index of the active Y scale, and make it visible or invisible in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add and remove scales programmatically.
But you can hide/show existing scales.
So you should configure a preset list of scales, then show/hide them according to your needs.

Here is an code snippet. Drag and drop the picture in your block diagram in order to have the ready to use code.

[image]